# How to pass background task identifier to completion handler?

Tags: ios, swift

I see many examples using a class member variable to pass the value of background task to completion block:

```
self.bgTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    .beginBackgroundTaskWithName("bg task", expirationHandler: { () -> Void in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.bgTask)
        self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
        })
```

If this code is called twice, second time while the first background task is still running, then `self.bgTask` will get overwritten with the new task's identifier, and `UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.bgTask)` may never get called.

If I declare a local variable instead, then its value is captured by closure before being initialized. No good either.

How can I pass task ID to its completion handler safely? If my reasoning above is wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ObjC, you would generally do this using a `__block` variable, for example:

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"Expired: %lu", (unsigned long)bgTask);
    }];
NSLog(@"Background: %lu", (unsigned long)bgTask);
```

This captures `bgTask` as a mutable variable for the block. It's moved to the heap when the block is copied, and the local variable `bgTask` is made an indirect pointer to it. See bbum's more extensive explanation in [Blocks Tips & Tricks](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/08/29/blocks-tips-tricks/).

If you wanted to then assign that to a property, that's fine, but you don't need to.

Swift doesn't have the `__block` attribute, but it does the right thing without any help. You just need to give it a `var` to work with.

```
func goBackground() {
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = 0
    bgTask = app.beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({
        NSLog("Expired: %lu", bgTask)
        app.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
    })
    NSLog("Background: %lu", bgTask)
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    goBackground()
    goBackground()
}
```

Again, there's no need to store the value in a property unless you want it for some other reason. The value is stored as a local variable inside the closure.

This is an important thing to learn about closures and is a very powerful feature of Swift. It's the same thing that lets you do this:

```
var n = 0
let nextNat = { n++ }

println(nextNat()) // => 0
println(nextNat()) // => 1
```

Comment: Ahh... so Swift won't allow me to declare a variable and bind to it in a closure on the same line. Declaring `var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = 0` on a separate line makes the compiler happy.

Comment: Correct. The variable must already exist for the closure to capture it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to end previous task and start a new task
`

```
var uiBackgroundTaskIdentifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(rawValue: 0)

func beingOrEndBackgroundUpdateTask() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState {
        case .background, .inactive:
            beginBackgroundUpdateTask()
        case .active:
            endBackgroundUpdateTask()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() {
    // end previous task
    endBackgroundUpdateTask()
    self.uiBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask (withName: "Finish Network Tasks") {
        // End the task if time expires.
        self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()
    }
}

func endBackgroundUpdateTask() {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.uiBackgroundTaskIdentifier)
    self.uiBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
}
```

`